# Which Call is better sencha touch Ajax or jquery ajax for android mobile application?

Tags: android, jquery, sencha-touch-2.1

Hello Every one am developing application in sencha touch 2, with cord-ova,  before starting it i want to know which call is better to get data fast from service, and please explain why ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ive used both of these platforms in building a custom mobile apps.

Sencha Touch takes much much longer to learn and become comfortable with, but it's more robust. Sencha Touch documentation and examples, however, are quite unrefined in my opinion. There's almost no MVC architecture support docs, so be prepared to do a lot of reverse engineering.

jQuery Mobile can get you up and running in a day, but it's not as feature rich, and seems not quite as smooth in terms of transitions and effects.

Sencha Touch has a better development roadmap than JQuery Mobile and a more focused dev team .  Sencha Touch is now free of license fees and considering that you may be extending a web app into mobile as a channel, I've found about 40% reuse of extjs code into from a Sencha web app into Sencha Touch .  Additionally a full blown SVG charting add-on to Sencha Touch is soon to come.

JQuery Mobile might be more suitable for a CMS driven site that wants to add a web client/reader.  JQuery has a larger network of overall users, but I'd argue most rarely extend classes as much as they do implement widgets.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using either the FRAMEWORK Sencha Touch or the LIBRARY JQuery Mobile only for Ajax calls, then you should concider writing the call yourself (it's rather easy - really - just about two lines of code).

But if you need to know which of the two you should use, then I would recommend:

- are you writing desktop websites too --> use jQuery
- are you willing to dive deep into a framework --> you are rewarded deeply by Sencha Touch